# Required autocomplete field

Tags: views, entities

I have an 'Entity Reference' autocomplete field populated by a view that returns all authenticated user email addresses.  I have set the field to 'Required' but when I enter an email address not in the list and save the node, it doesn't trigger an error.  It just makes the field blank.  Is there anything I can do to force the node not to save if a valid email address has not been entered?

Comment: You could add your own validation function to the form via a form_alter

Comment: That would work. I was hoping for something a little simpler that doesn't require code.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing the no results message in the view, maybe have return an invalid address like a@a@a.c or something.